# Sitefinity extra application

Tags: sitefinity

Within Sitefinity application can I add extra application with different application pools. So in the root folder will display the normal site but also have an folder like `Tool` that will house API calls?

```
www.site.com
www.site.com\Tool
```

Comment: Why do you want a different application pool for the api? Sitefinity has a huge collection of OData apis, so why not use those?

Comment: Yes a different application pool , area that will not interfere with sitefinity. the tools have been build and we don’t have time to rebuilt them.

Comment: ah, so /tool will be a completely different application? it should be fine, but you may need to do some adjustments to the web.config of that other application because some settings may collide with the parent web.config file (the one from the sitefinity site)

Comment: @veselin-vasilev is there setting in  the sitefinity web.config file that will need to be set?

Comment: I can't think of anything specific, but I guess it all depends on what's in the web.config of this other application. Are there any errors ?